# Updating dependencies gulp dependencies in Visual Studio

Tags: node.js, azure, visual-studio-2015, gulp, asp.net-core

I'm working on a new ASP.NET 5 project in Visual Studio 2015 and I'm really lost with all the frontend package management business.

This is a brand new project and when I publish it to Azure, I get a whole bunch of warnings -- some of which are breaking our builds on Azure.

Here's one such warning -- this doesn't seem to break anything but I want to get rid of it.

> npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\MyDocuments\documents\visual studio
>   2015\Projects\MyProject\src\MyProject\node_modules\gulp-cssmin\node_modules\gulp-util
>   requires minimist@'^0.2.0' but will load

I don't know how to update "minimist". I open Node.js Interactive Window in Visual Studio but when I type

> npm install minimist

I get the this error:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

I seem to get this SyntaxError no matter what I type in there. Like I said, I don't know Node.js -- which is in my list of things to learn but I have other priorities right now.

How do I update minimist and how do I handle these node.js errors and warnings that keep breaking our builds?

Comment: Hmm, I just ran ".npm install minimist" in a node.js project and that installed for me.

Answer (score 0):

Are you adding the new package you want to package.json? After saving that file, VS should go out and install the dependency.

The file might be hidden, so be sure to "Show All Files" in your solution explorer.

Comment: I didn't add anything to package.json because I didn't add any of those packages listed under node_modules/gulp-cssmin/node_modules. I must have some 20+ packages in that folder and I didn't add any of them. They must have come with the new ASP.NET project. None of those packages are in the package.json file.

Answer (score 0):

It seems this is `gulp-cssmin` dependencies missing issue. And I searched posts with several similar issues, they might solve this problem in reinstalling the node dependencies.

You can try to delete the `gulp-cssmin` folder under the node_modules in your project directory. Then run `npm install gulp-cssmin --save` to reinstall the node module, and the option `--save` will instruct NPM to include the package inside of the `dependencies` section of your `package.json` automatically.

And you can try to configure all your dependencies in `package.json` inside of the `dependencies` section, and delete the node_modules folder in your project directory, then run `npm install` to install all the dependencies configured in `package.json` file.